# inconsistent line spacing for quotes

Tags: spacing, line

Although I did not change anything for spacing part, line spacings are different between quotes. I can only use LaTex packages in the list of accepted packages. (https://authors.acm.org/proceedings/production-information/accepted-latex-packages)
What should I check for this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide a code example that generates your issue. The example should be complete (including relevant class and preamble) but minimal so that it does not include anything irrelevant. Without a code example, we have no idea what you are doing and basically cannot help.